# cloud firestore test mode vs locked mode what differences?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I`m confusing what differences this firebase ask two types first is Cloud Firestore Locked Mode and Second is Cloud Firestore Test Mode.im totally confuse these two types plz any one explain me with example & What can i use ...?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#default_rules_locked_mode

Comment: Thanks very help full your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#create) are the official documents.

Generally, the modes are related with the kind of users that can handle a project's data (read, write)...